# Project Euler using Python, Regarding definition of multiples

Tags: python

I started programming recently, my first language being python. I know just the basics of the language including conditionals, loops, range and some other functions.

I tried to solve project euler's problem 1 using python. The problem statement is as follows:

*If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.*

Here's my solution:

```
z=0
for x in range(0,1000,1):
    if type(x%3)==int or type(x%5)==int:
        z=x+z
print z
```

The answer i get is 499500 which is wrong. I tried searching for an answer and found that replacing the third line of my solution:

```
if type(x%3)==int or type(x%5)==int
```

with

```
if x%3==0 or x%5==0
```

yields the correct answer which is **233168.**

Why is my code wrong? So far as I'm aware, a multiple need not leave the remainder as zero. For instance, 255 is a multiple of 5. But 255%5 does not leave the remainder as zero. So how does the line *if x%3==0 or x%5==0* correct the answer when in fact, it ignores the definition of multiples.

Or perhaps I have wrongly assumed what multiples are. Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried looking at what type you *do* get for integer and non-integer multiples? Why did you think that would be a useful thing to discriminate on?

Comment: becouse `type(x%3)` is `type int` sometimes (for example, `3%2 = 1` and `1` is of type `int` => your condition is `is 1 int?` which is wrongly true - you dont care about `type` but about _modulo == zero_) so `x%3 == 0` => _x modulo 3 = 0_  is right condition :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your original code, is that [Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) with natural numbers always yields a natural number.

```
print type(4%3)
#print <type 'int'>
print type(4%3)==int
#print True
```

So, what you are doing is basically summing all numbers between 0 and 1000:

```
print sum(range(0,1000,1))
#prints 499500
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

a is a multiple of b iff `a = k b` with k an integer. Then `%` is modulo, which is defined like that:

```
a % b = z iff a = k b + z with k (and z) integers (and 0 <= z < b)
```

Therefore if `z= 0`, then `a = k b` and a is a multiple of b.